# Ionic navbar buttons - right side

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm starting to use Ionic for the first time. Currently I have a `listview` and the back button appears when moving into the list.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
    Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

How do I add a button on the right of the screen now, also only appearing once moving into the list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `<ion-header-bar align-title="right">`

<strike>Full implementation (both left and right) (from [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionHeaderBar/)):</strike>

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" ng-click="doSomething()">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  Some content!
</ion-content>
```

As pointed out by Harry, adding `ion-nav-buttons` and setting `side=right` is the right way of accomplishing this.

(Copied from @harry's answer)

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
        Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reset()">
            Refresh
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it doesn't make use of the nav-bar, so you lose the state management provided by the routing system. Read more about the differences between the two approaches here: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-bar-vs-header-bar/

Answer (score 26):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
        Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reset()">
            Refresh
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Comment: wouldnt this give me a button on all the tabs? what if i have multiple tabs and i want different buttons based on the tab. Is there any similar solution for that. I dont want to use `ion-header-bar`

Answer (score 4):

`<ion-nav-buttons>` is what you're looking for: [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavButtons/)

This took me a long time to find, but it works just great. Just put `side="right"` as the attribute.

It would be nice if this was more apparent in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ionic 4 Header]

```html
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title class="titleHeader">User Detail</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

You can find the answer from here also : [Ionic 2 / 3 / 4 : How to align button in the header to the right side of header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005630/ionic-2-3-4-how-to-align-button-in-the-header-to-the-right-side-of-header/55508214#55508214)