# Ionic 2 / 3 / 4 : How to align button in the header to the right side of header

Tags: html, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

How can I align with the right side, the button is showing on the left of the header without compose icon.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-title>TODO APP</ion-title>
<button class = "button button-icon">
    <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
</button>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: Hi! Don't forget to mark your issue as resolved by selecting the answer that has been the more useful to you. It will help other people ;-)

Answer (score 29):

Ionic 2 / Ionic 3 has something for that, just look at the following code :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>
      My Page
    </ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="myFunction()" ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The advantage of solving your problem this way is that your navbar will automatically respect the android/ios/windows guidelines. So this way you improve the quality of your app.

More informations about the guidelines :

**Android** :
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

**iOS** :
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/

**Windows** :
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/design

Comment: The ion-buttons tag with end attribute is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome dude! Hope I'll be able to help you more one day haha ;-)

Comment: what if i have just one button to the left , and i need the title to be in the center of the ion-header , not the center of ion-title (to be center exactly)

Answer (score 7):

ionic 4 ion-navbar is replaced by ion-back-button and in **Ionic 4** back button be like

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
       <ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
       </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
     Home
    </ion-title>
      <ion-button slot="secondary">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: It would be best to edit that information into your answer rather than a comment so it becomes complete.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. `<ion-button slot="end">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>`

Answer (score 4):

You can add button in right side in header in [ionic 2.0](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#button-sizes)

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
    <ion-title>
        TODO APP
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ><ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

You can add your custom icon's css class like this

**css**

```
.ion-ios-custom:before {
    background-image: url("image-icon.png");        
 }
```

**OR**

```
.ion-ios-custom:before {       
   content: "\f439"; /* your font code */
 }
```

**OR**

```
.ion-ios-custom:before {
   content: url("image-icon.png") !important;
}
```

**html**

```
<ion-icon name="custom"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: if there should be icon of compose, then?

Comment: you can add your class name if compose icon is available there.

Comment: I just read from documentation that :To use an icon, just add the Icon’s CSS class to your element, how to do that where is icon's css class

Answer (score 4):

It's work for me.

> Ionic 4 - Header

[image]

```html
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title class="titleHeader">User Detail</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="end">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this:

```
ion-buttons {
    order: 10
}
```

Try adding it to your stylesheet

**Note:** I used this in ionic2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-toolbar color='primary'>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name='menu'></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>TODO APP</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
        <button (click)='YOUR_FUNCTION_CALL' ion-button icon-only>
            <ion-icon name='YOUR_ICON_NAME'></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Replace:

1. YOUR_FUNCTION_CALL with the function call you need to call when click
2. YOUR_ICON_NAME  with icon name

for icons please visit this website http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done as follow:

```
 <ion-header class="ion-no-border">
   <ion-toolbar>
     <ion-button slot="start">
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
     </ion-button>
     <ion-title>
       utenze
     </ion-title>
     <ion-button slot="end">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
     </ion-button>
   </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<ion-view title="home" align-title="center">    
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">        
        <button ng-click="search()" class="button button-icon icon ion-android-search"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>    
    <ion-content has-bouncing="0px">
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

this should work for you ......